# Adding two float variable returns integer Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add two float variable in SQL Server but it returns integer value.It returns 1.How can I avoid this.

I tried to casting query but it doesn't help me.

Here I tried adding query:

```
 CAST(STDE.d1 AS FLOAT) + CAST(STDE.d2 AS FLOAT) AS STD_e
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: the result of your query should certainly be a `FLOAT`

Comment: How do you check that "it returns 1"? How do you evaluate `STD_e`? How do you know "1" is not the correct answer?

Comment: Yes division works well

Comment: d1 is 0.974952118162636   and d2 is 0.0250478818373641 but when its adding equal "1" Why that happened? Question is that @Jeron Moster

Comment: where are you verifying  the results ? ssms or outside of it (eg. Visual Studio)?

Comment: It is Navicate @Milen

Comment: @coder3 because the result is `1.0000000000000001` and for a float is perfectly fine to round it to `1`. Are you expecting an exact result?, then don't use an approximate data type

Comment: If you want an atrociously precise answer with all decimals, you'll need to ask for it. `SELECT CAST(0.974952118162636 AS DECIMAL(18, 18)) + CAST(0.0250478818373641 AS DECIMAL(18, 18))` is `1.000000000000000100`, exactly.